# JQuery y validate plugin

Tags: jquery

Estoy empezando a programar y no tengo mucha experiencia con Jquery. La cosa es que tengo que hacer un ejercicio para practicar JQuery y ando perdido. Lo que tengo que hacer es un formulario con un NIF, nombre y apellidos, usar localStorage para comprobar si está registrado de antes o no... etc. Hasta ahí todo bien, además las validaciones están bien y cumplen con lo que pido pero... tengo un gran PERO. El enunciado no es muy lógico pero está puesto así para practicar con ocultar y mostrar cosas:

"En el supuesto caso de que la persona sepa que no está registrada y pulse el botón de REGISTRARSE, se deberá cambiar el texto del encabezado INICIAR SESIÓN por el de REGISTRARSE y ocultaremos el botón de INICIAR. (Esto lo llevo bien, creo)

Por otra parte, si el cliente no sabe si se ha registrado o no e intenta registrarse, se le indicará mediante un mensaje que está dado de alta, se pasarán sus datos a la interfaz modificada de INICIAR SESIÓN y el botón que deberá aparecer es el de INICIAR." <-- Aquí está el problema. Para validar se tiene que usar un botón tipo submit, cuando pulsas, aunque haya indicado que cambie el encabezado y oculte el botón de "Registrar", al ser un submit se recarga la página de nuevo. Se ve que se ha cambiado el encabezado y el botón durante una milésima de segundo pero claro, no se queda ahí.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="contenedorexterno" align="center">
    <h2>Iniciar sesión</h2>
    <form name="formulario_logeo" id="formulario_logeo" action="" method="POST">
        <label for="nif">NIF</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="nif" id="nif" placeholder="NIF">
            <br>

            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">

            <br>

            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">

            <br>            
        <button type="submit" id="enviar">Iniciar</button>
        <button type="button" id="registro">Registrar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#enviar').click(function(){

    //recojo los valores del formulario y los almaceno en variables
    var nif=$('#nif').val();
    var nombre=$('#nombre').val();
    var apellidos=$('#apellidos').val();


    var valid=true; //establecemos una variable booleana para que no se puedan meter campos vacíos

    if(nif=="" || niflogeo==""){ 
        valid=false;
    }
    if(nombre==""){
        valid=false;
    }
    if(apellidos==""){
        valid=false;
    }


    //miramos el localStorage para obtener objeto NIF
    var niflogeo=localStorage.getItem('nif');

    if(nif==niflogeo){ //si el nif coincide con lo ya almacenado en localStorage

        alert("Su NIF está registrado");
        $("#registro").hide();
        $("body").html("<div align='center'><h1 style='margin-top:15%;'>Bienvenidx!</h1></div>");

 //Aquí todo bien.

    }else if(valid && nif!==niflogeo){ //si el nif NO coincide con lo almacenado en localStorage

        localStorage.setItem('nif', nif); //metemos el nif nuevo, en localSorage
        alert("Su NIF no está registrado"); //APARECE EL ALERT, 
   // pero aquí, en vez de continuar con el JQuery siguiente, se recarga la página
  // si pongo un type button funciona, pero no se cumplen las validaciones
 // y tampoco tiene sentido no usar un submit en un formulario.
        $("h2").text("Registro");
        $("#enviar").text("Registrar");
        $("#registro").hide();
    }

    localStorage.setItem('nombre', nombre);
    localStorage.setItem('apellidos', apellidos);


});


$("#registro").click(function(){

    $("h2").text("Registro");
    $("#enviar").text("Registrar");
    $("#registro").hide();
 //Esto también bien.
 });
});
```

Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copiaré solo la sección de código que precisas modificar

```
$('#enviar').click(function(e){//e es la variable e se guarda el evento que se realiza
```

y más abajo:

```
else if(valid && nif!==niflogeo){ //si el nif NO coincide con lo almacenado en localStorage
        e.preventDefault() // Esto hará que el evento submit no se realice y te permite continuar
        localStorage.setItem('nif', nif);
        alert("Su NIF no está registrado"); 
        $("h2").text("Registro");
        $("#enviar").text("Registrar");
        $("#registro").hide();
    }
```

Comment: Genial. Muchísimas gracias!! :)